# TeamCity Android Proguard results in "Your input classes appear to be inconsistent."

Tags: teamcity, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

When I build my Android project from the command line with

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

It works, but when I run it from my teamcity build agent the build gives a lot of warnings and fails witht he following errors:

```
[11:40:43][Step 4/10] Warning: there were 75 unresolved references to program class members.
[11:40:43][Step 4/10]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[11:40:43][Step 4/10]          You may need to recompile the code.
[11:40:43][Step 4/10]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
[11:40:43][Step 4/10] :proguardRelease FAILED
```

I've tried modifying my build config to run gradlew from command line instead of using the gradle build runner but it is still broken. There is obviously something different between running the command from TeamCity versus running it manually through command line, but I don't know what that could be. Where to look?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem and solution are right what it says on the tin:

> Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
>
> You may need to recompile the code.

Given you're using Gradle, it's possible one version of gradle doesn't match the other or doesn't behave the same. This is particularly true if e.g. you've upgraded gradle from an older version.

Fix is simple: `gradle clean` or `gradlew clean` then try again.

Comment: That didn't work, however my build is working now after recreating the build environment in another directory. It doesn't make sense. Thanks for the help.